# Pass locale to axios request

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm doing a project in React + redux and I'm consuming a API. I want to pass to the API the locale of the current user without passing as a parameter. Can I pass the locale as a header in the axios GET request? Or do you have another suggestion? I need to pass because the API will return to me translated strings.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although a year old, I think you deserve an answer :) Well, you can surely pass a locale as header in the GET request, for example:

```
axios.get(URL, { headers: { YourLocale: 'something' } }).then(...).catch(...)
```

but your question wasn't really React related, instead if the API returns a translated string, it means it also expects the locale in specific way(s), whether a parameter or header. So you need to pass the locale however the API expects it :)

Comment: Thank you for the response!! Although I did in a diferente way, it's good to know that I can do this :]